# iOS App terminates due to bad value of NSDecimalNumber

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, nsdecimalnumber

My iOS app terminates in Xcode simulator due to EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on following line

```
if ([amount.text isEqualToString:@""] || [chargeAmount floatValue] == 0.0) {
```

The complete block of code is

```
if ([amount.text isEqualToString:@""] || [chargeAmount floatValue] == 0.0) {
    // Focus on the poptip target.
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [transactionView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    [self performSelector:@selector(amountRequiredPopup) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
    return;
}
```

I check amount.text in NSLog and it is showing the value but not the ChargeAmount. It seems there is bad value of chargeAmount. chargeAmount is defined in interface in .h file as follows:

```
NSDecimalNumber* chargeAmount;
```

I am new in objective C and iOS app development. Please suggest where is the issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is `chargeAmount` initialized?

Comment: @vadian in the .h file as below:

`@interface TransactionFormViewController : GAITrackedViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, CurrenciesViewControllerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate> {
 IBOutlet UITextField *amount;
    IBOutlet UITextField *discount; 
    
    NSDecimalNumber* chargeAmount; // defined here
    NSDecimalNumber* discountAmount;
    NSDecimalNumber* totalChargeAmount;
    
    InputType inputType;
}`

Comment: @vadian its wierd because you can call [chargeAmount floatValue] even if chargeAmount is nil and this not crash the app, tested with     `NSDecimalNumber* chargeAmount;` `NSLog(@"%f",[chargeAmount floatValue]);` this no crash at all

Comment: In the .h file it's **defined**. I'm asking where it's **initialized** (assigning a value to it). And which exception reason do you get?

Comment: I think that the problem is `[amount.text isEqualToString:@""]`can you check if `amount.text`is nil? please put an NSLog(@"%@",amount.text) and post what prints the console

Comment: @vadian I am not sure about this, I couldn't see any where in both files about initialization.

Comment: @ReinierMelian thanks for the reply. Let me check that please.

Comment: @ReinierMelian I checked `amount.text` and it is showing the value, the problem is in `chargeAmount`. But I am not sure what is the issue actually.

Comment: must be another kind of issue because I tested even if chargeAmount is nil this don´t crash the app, maybe you are putting there another type, can you please post all your crash log message?

Comment: I am not sure about crash log, I can see following message in the console.

`2017-07-31 13:00:59.418170 SwipeHQC[69083:3405474] [] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash simulate crash already simulated "nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available"`

Comment: first add a IOS enviroment variable to avoid those logs, go to your app scheme and go to edit scheme and add  this in a section called Eviroment Variables add this `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE`and in value put Disable, let me know when you have done this

Comment: Yes I did this now.

Comment: @yas then try to get the message of your crash must be EXC_BAD_ACCESS and something else

Comment: Now the last message in the console is as follow:

`2017-07-31 13:23:22.751 App[69974:3423386] Can't find keyplane that supports type 8 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-DecimalPad; using 309711205_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default`

Comment: is hard to explain without images, add an exception breakpoint, do you know how do it?

Comment: I don't know that but I will check that. Should I add that just above that line of code?

Comment: @Yas check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode when you have done this let me know

Comment: @ReinierMelian I added exception break point and now, it is showing the following error:

`[NSMutableRLEArray floatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ba141f0`

Comment: @Yas my answer finally help you? can you accept my answer? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your last comment, as i think the issue is that you have assigned a value of another type into your `chargeAmount` variable, search all your code related to `chargeAmount` and post there, in some part of your code you are assigning a value of type `NSMutableAttributedString` to your  `chargeAmount` variable and then when you call `[chargeAmount floatValue]` crash because NSMutableAttributedString don't have any method called `floatValue`

Hope this helps you

Comment: chargeAmount is defined in .h file as `NSDecimalNumber* chargeAmount;` and then being used in .m file as `if ([amount.text isEqualToString:@""] || [chargeAmount floatValue] == 0.0) {`, at same point it is being crashed. I thing there should be some thing else than `floatValue` but I am not sure what should be, please suggest.

Comment: @Yas check the class of your chargeAmount before the crash, something like    ` NSLog(@"%@",[chargeAmount class]);` and let me know what prints

Comment: I did this and it is crashing on this line  ` NSLog(@"%@",[chargeAmount class]);` as well. But just to check if I assign a value 0, `chargeAmount = 0;` and then it is displaying `null` for class and not crashing as well.

Comment: I added the line of code `chargeAmount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:amount.text];` above that block and it solved the issue.

Actually chargeAmount was not given any value so it was crashing at float conversion. Thank you for your help and answer.

Comment: @Yas I am glad to help you, and hear that finally the issue is solved

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead of `NSDecimalNumber* chargeAmount;` you can define that variable as `float` and set its value to `0.0` in `viewDidLoad()` and then later you can set it to as per your code and add that check on it.

Comment: did you try NSLog(@"%f",[chargeAmount floatValue]) this not crash at all, even if chargeAmount is not initialized